# How do I calculate the range that 90% of the values fall into

Tags: descriptive-statistics

Given a series of values, I know that 68% of the values fall withing one standard deviation and that 95% fall withing 2 standard deviations, but how do I calculate the range whereby 90% percent of the values will fall. Lets call that 90% range the typical range.

Comment: Mutuel, In light of Glen_b's excellent comments, I am wondering about your objective here: do you seek to *describe* your data by giving bounds containing 90% of them or perhaps do you seek to *draw an inference* about a population of which your data are a representative sample?

Answer (score 3):

> Given a series of values, I know that 68% of the values fall within one standard deviation and that 95% fall within 2 standard deviations,

This won't be true as a general statement, sometimes not even approximately.

-- aside

To clarify -

@whuber points out that they're often good approximations - which is true. (The 2 s.d. case in particular seems to be pretty robust; if you have unimodal continuous data that's  not too asymmetric, the 2 s.d. rule can't be out by more than about 7%.) But stated as a general claim, as I attempted to point out, it's not the case. It can be that they're not even roughly in the ballpark. I have encountered real data (very often!) that gets very close to 100% inside 1 s.d. of the mean - indeed, there's some in my R session right now that I was playing with just a short time ago (some insurance data). I have also encountered (a few times) data that had very close to 0% within 1 s.d. of the mean. For example, I've seen Likert scale data that was very close to evenly split at the extremes, with only a very small percentage in the inner categories between them. It really happens.

Consider two samples of 100 observations. One has 98 0's and a -1 and a 1. The other has two zeros and 49 -1's and 49 1's. The first has 98% of the data within one s.d. of the mean, while the second has 2% within one s.d. of the mean. (The real data I've seen isn't quite so 'neat', but the percentages aren't so different.)

If you use R, these vectors contain those samples:

```
x1<-c(-1,1,rep(0,98))
x2<-c(0,0,rep(-1,49),rep(1,49))
```

-- end aside

You appear to have left some conditions out.

> how do I calculate the range whereby 90% percent of the values will fall. Lets call that 90% range the typical range

***If*** you mean 'for normally distributed data' (which you had better specify), and assuming a symmetric interval then you just find the 5th and 95th percentiles of the normal distribution. Those are about 1.645 sd's either side of the mean.

You can look them up in normal tables, or you can use a program to find them for you.

--

Edit: It's *also* possible to generate nonparametric intervals based on sample quantiles, such as tolerance intervals or predictions intervals (depending on the precise form of the probability statement you wish to make). These are less efficient than when your data really has whatever parametric form you assume, but they don't rely on any parametric assumption.

Comment: So are you saying that plus or minus 1 standard deviation around the mean does not represent 68% of the values assuming a normal distribution.

Comment: You didn't say 'assuming a normal distribution'. Why would I assume a normal distribution if you didn't say to? It's not the case in general. Your actual condition was 'given a series of values'. Even with the sample coming from a normal distribution, the sample proportions needn't reflect the population.

Comment: I think you're reacting a little too severely, Glen_b: the 68-95-99.7% rule is a strikingly good approximation for many datasets, even visibly non-normal ones. Although you are correct to point out it *is* an approximation and *will* be violated in some circumstances, I think your initial comment ("not ... even approximately") is too extreme.

Comment: @whuber Given that Bernoulli data is common, and trinomial data (say on 0,1,2 or -1,0,1) - while clearly much less common - isn't exactly ultra-rare, real data either at or very close to the limiting cases I mentioned are easily possible. It's not some bizarre never-to-be-seen contrivance, we really could get nearly 0% or nearly 100% within 1 s.d. of the mean in a real data set. I do regard "near 0%" and "near 100%" as not "approximately 68%".

Comment: We may be talking at cross-purposes, Glen: I have acknowledged that there are exceptions; you are quite right about them. I am only urging you to pull back from your extreme position that practically *everything* is an exception! ("Not in general.") In the case of "Bernoulli data," usually these are summarized by counts, giving them *Binomial* distributions, which--even in fairly skewed cases--still come remarkably close to satisfying the 68% and 95% rules of thumb. (The length of one tail counterbalances the shortness of the other.)

Comment: The intent wasn't that 'practically everything is an exception' but that 'this is not true as a general statement' - I have changed the language to be less misleading/more closely reflect my intent, and included specific examples.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether the data are Normal, uniform, or quite a few other distributions, there are ways to calculate a range wherein 90% of the data fit.

The usual assumption is that you want the *middle* 90%. In this case, find the 5%tile and the 95%tile and that is your answer. There can be some problems with ties, and there are at least 5 definitions of "quantile" but that is the basic idea.

Of course, 90% also fit between the minimum and the 90th %tile

In `R` you can get the 5 and percentiles with the `quantile` function. E.g.

```
set.seed(10201082)
x <- runif(1000,0,10)

quantile(x, probs = c(.05, .95))
```

with this data, 56% is within 1 sd:

```
sum(x > 5 - sd(x) & x < 5 + sd(x))
```

and all is within 2 sd